# Reuse an MVC area in multiple MVC applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have some common web pages that will be in multiple MVC applications. For those pages I'd like to reuse the same source code (controllers + views) between the different MVC web sites. What is the best way to go about doing this?

ASP.NET MVC areas seem like one possibility but they just a sub directory of the website project. Is it possible to reuse an MVC area in multiple MVC applications?

Answer (score 4):

You could [embed views into assemblies and implement a custom VirtualPathProvider](http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins/).

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mcintyre321/EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider#readme for one such Nugettable provider

Answer (score 3):

Look at "portable areas."

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx